Reputation league quarterly view/"own" rep seems broken
I'm not sure if it's intermittent. I'm seeing variants of this on other sites as well, and other views, but my 'own' reputation for the quarter's both slightly inconsistent, and broken at times. I am not sure how to replicate this; I saw missing rep on the all time leagues on SU, but it fixed itself.


I couldn't be bothered to report this: it only happens when you visit somebody's link (here, yours, but it doesn't have to be). We've had a similar issue before.

Related: Switching back to "Week Rank" sorting in the reputation leagues is broken
